# jQuery refresh form elements onload

Tags: jquery, html, dom, browser, onload

I have this HTML form

```html
<form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" id="js-item" /> Select me</label>
    <div id="js-text" style="display:none;">You selected an item</div>
</form>
```

And some jQuery JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#js-item',function(){
        $('#js-text').show();        
    });
});
```

When the user clicks the radio button, the div shows itself. But when navigating away from this page (for example through a submit, or clicking a link) and pressing the back button in the browser, the radio item is being reselected by the browser. But the div isn't also showing (like it was selected). The show() event isn't triggered

How can I trigger **all** the form input handlers onload to the form current state set by the browser when navigating back for example? *without the need to duplicate all logic code*

Any help appreciated. Regards

**SOLUTION**

Based on the feedback, I created this, maybe it helps someone.

```html
<form>
    <label><input type="radio" data-toggle="js-text" /> Select me</label>
    <div id="js-text">You selected an item</div>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*[data-toggle]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $toggle_el = $('#'+$(this).data('toggle'));

        $this.is(':checked') ? $toggle_el.show() : $toggle_el.hide();
        $(document).on('click', $this, function (e) {
            $this.is(':checked') ? $toggle_el.slideDown('fast') : $toggle_el.hide();
        });
    });

});
```

if you want to dismiss any flickering, you have to add hidden classes to the elements that toggle visibility. Thanks.

Comment: You've attached a `click` handler, and then you're triggering a `change` handler. If you haven't attached a `change` handler nothing will happen.

Comment: Problem with click, is that all items will be clicked and thefore the last item in a radio buttons list will be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the radio button is checked like this

```
$('#js-item').is(':checked')
```

So, on document ready you can immediately show you div, when `#js-item` is checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    yourFunction();
    $(document).on('change','form', yourFunction);
});

function yourFunction() {
    $('#js-item').is(':checked') ? $('#js-text').show() : $('#js-text').hide();    
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pmYYh/2/

For none duplicate code, extract the logic to a function.

Comment: This is duplicating all the logic code. I am looking for a piece of code that walks through the entire form and reads out their state and handles the already present handlers.

Comment: If you extract the code of the event to a function, and just call the function instead doing `$('#js-text').show(); `?

Answer (score 1):

I generally do this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        showHideText(); //check for all on form load 
        $(document).on('click','#js-item',function(){ 
            showHideText('js');       
        });
    });
    function showHideText(id){
     if (id){ //check for specific id
      if($('#'+id+'-item').is(':checked')) {
                  $('#'+id+'-text').show();       
            }
    }else{ //check for all
        // for each of your ids do the above check...
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need clarifications

Comment: Ah, yeah so in essence, it's separating the logic code to a function and calling the same code to the event handlers and the onload. Makes sense

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio').attr({checked:false});

    $(document).on('click','#js-item',function(){
        $('#js-text').show();        
    });
});
```